# How to prevent Content Security Policy errors with testcafe electron plugin?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, electron, content-security-policy, testcafe

I'm getting a lot of Content Security errors in the console when trying to run my electron app in Testcafe:

*VM110 pagewrap.bundle.js:3 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Z+HxFhVCHMznEI/lLsU2FT9krRiVCTm6bGApEd5HAtk='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*

Tested with different electron versions (4,6,7) on Linux. (with version 0.0.14 of the provider plugin)
I also tried to add

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"  content="default-src 'unsafe-inline'; etc." />`

just for testing but it didn't help

I'm not even sure if the right mainWindowUrl is loaded since I only see a black page showing the electron version and my OS and tthe URLS are looking like http://192.168.178.79:37961...

Is there a way to debug the loading process of testcafe or any hint how to prevent these errors?

Comment: I managed to avoid the error by setting 
'Content-Security-Policy': ['default-src \'unsafe-inline\' \'self\' \'unsafe-eval\'; img-src \'self\' data:;']
in response headers

But this policy should only apply in test context of course...

Answer (score 3):

TestCafe emulates Chrome's content security policies even when running tests in Electron. The difference between Chrome's and Electron's policies is that Electron treats all requests that have the `file:` origin as `same-domain` if the current page also has the `file:` origin. Chrome's policies are stricter: each different file path is treated as a different origin. Unfortunately, implementing such changes in content security policies can take a lot of time. You can use [issue #4208](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4208) to track our progress in updating security policies.